# Creating a PDF in ColdFusion?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

**How can dynamic HTML be put into a PDF using ColdFusion?**

This is in relation to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907745/i-cant-get-internet-explorer-to-properley-refresh-my-coldfusion-page) about getting IE to work properly with a CFDIV.

What I am trying to do is something similar to this

```
<cfdocument 
name="table"
format="PDF"> 
foo
<cfdiv id="content" bind="cfc:TestCFC.displayTable({filters})"></cfdiv>
bar
</cfdocument>
```

however when I open my PDF document, I only see

```
foo
bar
```

I would like a solution that uses the CFDIV with the bind, however if that is not an option than any solution will do.

Comment: As a side note, it is often makes more sense to me to wrap content in a <cfsavecontent> and output the variable you create in the cfdocument. Also, you have an extra /cfdiv up there.

Comment: Another point to keep in mind: in my experience, the quality of the PDF(s) layout is dependent on somewhat precise CSS. Once you have it working, it will take some time to perfect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use bind parameters for pdfs because the bind parameters are executed via AJAX on the client. You'll need to do something like this instead:

```
<cfdocument name="table" format="PDF"> 
foo
<cfdiv id="content"><cfoutput>#TestCFC.displayTable({filters})#</cfoutput></cfdiv>
bar
</cfdocument>
```

And you'll need to get the `filters` argument in there via some other method than a bind to another element. Possibly a `FORM` or `URL` variable when the user clicks the link or button to generate the PDF.